# Html Helper Check Box "Display Image"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image, razor, checkbox, html-helper

So I am not super familiar with html helpers or Razor syntax. Im sure there is a way to do what I am trying to do with those two, but im not entirely sure. Could be easier to do it via Controller, but I wanted to give it a go in the View. Here's some code:

```
<img src="@Url.Content(Model.Photo)" alt="@Model.AlternateText" />
```

So this displays my images perfectly as I'd like them to e displayed. Now I wanted to add a box that the user could check or uncheck, which would basically make the image visible or not. Is there a way to somehow integrate the html checkbox helper into my img? Something along these lines I suppose...

```
@Html.CheckBox("Photos", "Show Image")
<img src="@Url.Content(Model.Photo)" alt="@Model.AlternateText" />
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you planning on doing this with jQuery or by posting back and filtering the images? If the latter, what does your model look like (i.e. how are you mapping the checkboxes to the images)? If the former, you might be better off just using plain HTML. Helpers are generally only useful if you're trying to generate form fields that will bind back to a model class.

Answer (score 0):

What you have will work as far as the HTML part of the equation goes, though your syntax for `Html.CheckBox` is off. The second parameter is a boolean, indicating whether it should be initially checked or not. If you want "Show Image" to appear next to it, you'll need to just put the text in the view and preferably wrap the whole shebang with a label:

```
<label>@Html.CheckBox("Photos", false) Show Image</label>
```

Now, as far as showing and hiding the image, you'll need to use JavaScript for that. I've give you the jQuery version since it's simpler and it comes with MVC by default:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#Photos').on('click', function () {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                $('#Image').show();
            } else {
                $('#Image').hide();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Note: Based on passing a first parameter of "Photos" to `Html.CheckBox`, the resulting input will have both name and id attributes of "Photos" allowing you to select it by that id. If you change this value, you'll need to update the JS accordingly. Also, that code assumes adding an id of "Image" to your img tag. You can use whatever you want, but again, update the JS accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there are two ways you could go about this (I am presuming you want to be able to reuse this feature a lot hence the question to avoid lots of copy/paste code) :

1) Create a partial view where you pass the data required to this view.

2) Create a Html Helper that creates the html for you. Either extending the existing checkbox helper or creating your own.

Now it all depends on which one you are most familiar with doing.

The partial view may be the easiest to start off with and then you can build to the html helper afterwards if you wanted too.

For the toggling I guess you will need some simple javascript to do some show hide which could be done fairly simply either using an existing framework such as bootstrap or some simple jquery all you would need to do is have a reference of the image tag to the checkbox so that it knows that when it is checked that the image should change state.

if you need some code sample to give you a better idea of what I am trying to say then let me know and I will see what I knock up as an example.